# ng-disabled not working with bootstrap buttons

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap.js along with angular js, my code is following-

```
//few lines from controller
$scope.isWaiting = true;
$scope.promise = $http.get("voluumHandler.php?q=campaigns&filter=traffic-source&filterVal=" + traffic + "&from=" + from + "&to=" + to + "&tz=" + tz).success(function(response){        
        $scope.campaigns = response.rows;
        console.log(response.rows);
        $scope.isWaiting = false;
    }).error(function(response){
        alert(response);
        $scope.isWaiting = false;
    });
```

Here `isWaiting` is used for disabling and enabling the button.

```
<!--HTML -->
<div class="col-md-3">
        <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-disabled="{{isWaiting}}">Report</button>
    </div>
```

Output HTML produced before ajax load completed

```
<button class="btn btn-warning" ng-disabled="true" disabled="disabled">Report</button>
```

And after ajax load completed

```
<button class="btn btn-warning" ng-disabled="false" disabled="disabled">Report</button>
```

And button is still disabled. I am not sure why is this happening, I have seen couple of questions here answered to do this only.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are using `ng-disabled` an expression must be used that returns a truthy value. An example of an expression is `isWaiting`. `{{isWaiting}}`will instead output an expression. So instead use `ng-disabled="isWaiting"`.

```
<button class="btn btn-warning" ng-disabled="isWaiting">Report</button>
```

[ngDisabled documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled)

[Expressions documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression)

Comment: @WayneEllery But why though?

Comment: @PSL was that question addressed to me or codeomnitrix?

Comment: To you.. :) i was saying providing a small explanation in the answer would be great, you think? So future visitors dont wonder _Why_ :)

Answer (score 8):

You need to give **an expression** to `ng-disabled`, instead you are giving a string("true"/"false") which is always **truthy** and button is always disabled.

`isWaiting` --> expression

`{{isWaiting}}` --> value of expression

In your case:

```
ng-disabled="isWaiting"
```